# Facebook Cover page update

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When a cover page update it made, it becomes part of the timeline, but the same cannot be retrieved via feed or posts graph API.

How can i get these updates?

Regards,
Sesmic

Answer (score 0):

After changing something that not showing up in timeline (because of the API) you can call another request for example posting to wall or similar... So you should do it manually.